# undefined local variable or method after adding new base_controller - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The folder structure is as follows

> api -> v4> admin->rates->companies->base_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V4
      module Admin
          module Rates
               module Companies
                   class BaseController < ::Api::V4::ApplicationController
```

The sub controllers were extended from base_controller.

> api -> v4> admin->rates->companies->list_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V4
      module Admin
          module Rates
               module Companies
                   class ListController < BaseController
                          def show
                             authorize! :read, rate

                             render json: payload
                          end
```

This was working as expected.

Now i have a new base_controller outside this folder  in

> api -> v4> admin->rates->base_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V4
      module Admin
          module Rates
                   class BaseController < ::Api::V4::ApplicationController
```

After adding this file, i am getting error on list_controller.rb
**undefined local variable or method `rate' for #<Api::V4::Admin::RateSheets::Companies::ListController**

I assume now the list_controller is getting extended from new base_controller rather than the base_controller inside the companies folder.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Instead of explicitly referring to `::Api::V4::ApplicationController` just use `ApplicationController` and Ruby will look for the constant in the current module nesting. Resolving the constant from the root namespace is pretty wonky unless you actually need to refer to a constant in another nesting.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error here however which is very straight forward. You're calling `authorize! :read, rate` but you haven't declared a rate method anywhere.

Comment: @max The rate method is already defined in the base_controller

Comment: I think what you mentioned in the first comment makes sense. When i define class ListController < BaseController, ruby looks for the constant in the current module and picks the base_controller outside the "companies" folder. The file i needed should be called like ListController < Companies::BaseController

Comment: You're not actually giving us a reproducable example here. This is just a tiny snapshot of what you think the problem is (which most likely isn't actually the issue) and an error message. The problem could literally be anything - you declared it as a class instead of instance method, the wrong code is running or any other kind of programmer related error.